# Magento 2.3.5-p2 - Howto add company to customer adress information and billing address information in checkout?

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.3.5-p2, company

How can i add the company to these Blocks on checkout Page?

[image: show company in /checkout/#shipping]

[image: show company in /checkout/#payment]

I ve tried to add these Information to:

[image]

But it will not be displayed. Example given:

```
<if args="visible()">
<text args="address().company"/>
<text args="address().prefix"/> <text args="address().firstname"/> <text args="address().middlename"/>
<text args="address().lastname"/> <text args="address().suffix"/><br/>
<text args="_.values(address().street).join(', ')"/><br/>
<text args="address().city "/>, <span text="address().region"></span> <text args="address().postcode"/><br/>
<text args="getCountryName(address().countryId)"/><br/>
<a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a><br/>

<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
    <text args="$parent.getCustomAttributeLabel(element)"/>
    <br/>
</each>
```

Please Help...

Other Shops are working:

[image]

Comment: There is no default company field for customer address data, have you added this database field yourself?

Comment: it must be in magento 2.3.5-p2, it is shown in backend, you can see it in every form, but not in checkout...

Comment: Please try to fully compile and to deploy all static content. Had a similar issue and it only showed the edits AFTER going to production mode. All the manual cache and content updated dit not show until then.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is a company field which you can show by enabling it in **admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Name and Address Options -> Show company**.

Its display in the address forms is managed by Magento based on the configuration and you don't need to change anything.

Comment: Yes, got that, but it is not showing...
 In 2 of 3 Shops it is working, but not in this particular Shop...

Comment: oh... i'm thinking that the custom theme could be the issue?

Comment: could be, but the other shops got the same theme... 
Hard to find the difference, but i will try to find them if there